# Get memory utilization along with the file descriptors

Tags: linux, bash, shell, file-descriptor

I came up with a small script to send email whenever memory falls below 300 MB but at the same time I'm interested to get the open or active file descriptors that correspondingly consumes more memory and write those to the existing file - /tmp/memory.txt

I'm not exactly sure how to accommodate the request in my existing script. Any input would be really helpful.

```
subject="Check Memory Status"
to="myemail@domain.com"
ip=`ifconfig | grep -oP '(?<=inet addr:)\d+\.\d+\.\d+\d+'`

free=$(free -mt | grep Total | awk '{print $4}')

if [[ "$free" -le 300  ]]; then

   ps -eo pid,ppid,cmd,%mem,%cpu --sort=-%mem | head >/tmp/memory.txt
   file=/tmp/memory.txt
   echo -e "Warning, Memory is running low! on $ip\n Free memory: $free MB" | mailx -a "$file" -s "$subject" "$to"
fi
exit 0
```

Comment: Monitoring system resource utilization manually could be cumbersome. Try setting up https://collectd.org/

Comment: @Inian +1 for the alternative tool option . One question. have u implemented the collectd tool ?

Comment: Implemented the tool - No! But I’ve played with it a bit

Comment: For number operations/comparisons there is a double-round-brackets operator: `if (( free <= 300 )); then` (dedicated, more readable + you don't even need to use `$` when using it).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand your script checks for 'available' memory. Please bear in mind that 'buff/cache' is also free memory.

Interesting reading: https://www.linuxatemyram.com

You might find list of open files using `lsof` or `fopen` or even `/proc/PID/fd` if you need to find file descriptors.